# If in you besee-ee fit

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Oh father, dear father*

***If in you besee-ee fit***

*I'll send him to college for one year yet*

*I'll tie blue ribbons all around his head*

*To let the maidens know that he's married*

Source: https://genius.com/Donovan-young-but-growing-lyrics

Can you tell what the second line of the excerpt from Donovan's lyrics means? Not able to find the answer on the internet.

Comment: That should be _"If'n,"_ not _"if in."_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for interpretation of song lyrics / poetry

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP is asking about "if'n" or about "besee-ee".  I think it's a reasonable question, subject to the caveat **song lyrics are a terrible way to learn standard English**.

Comment: I do not understand the whole line in bold. If you could rewrite it into standard English, it would be very kind of you.

Comment: @Adam: If this question is indeed about ***If'n = IF*** (which I've always assumed was just an affected Southern US dialect, nothing to do with ***if and when***), I might be interested. But I doubt it is, since Donovan is *Scottish*, so he'd never sing it like that. People like [Joan Baez](http://www.metrolyrics.com/trees-they-do-grow-high-lyrics-joan-baez.html) might (though it's not transcribed thusly in that link), but OP has singled out Donovan here.

Comment: @stangdon: More to the point, I'd have though most people would agree that "rustic Texan / hillbilly" is ***a terrible English*** to learn! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers that there's fightin' words 'round certain parts!  ;)

Comment: @Andrew: Well, [Cletus in *The Simpsons*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-thrv47J-nQ) is a typical "mainstream" stereotypical depiction of the dialect. It doesn't exactly get a good press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transcription given is incorrect.  The correct transcription is:

> Oh father, dear father
>
> **If'n you see-ee fit**
>
> I'll send him to college for one year yet
>
> I'll tie blue ribbons all around his head
>
> To let the maidens know that he's married

***If'n:*** may be an archaic contraction of *if and,* or it may not be - regardless, here it means *"if."*

***besee/see:*** As noted in the comments, *besee* is an archaic word meaning "deem." That said, I don't hear the "be" at all in this recording: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9Y2uM82uHc&t=71

***see fit:*** *You see fit* means *"you approve."*

The speaker is asking for permission to take the steps she outlines next.  Essentially, the line means:

> If it is alright with you, then
>
> I'll send him to school for a year.

Comment: Thank you. But the odd form "besee" occurs in other webs where the lyrics in question is available.

Comment: Per my comment, I don't buy that "folksy" interpretation of Texan ***ifn***. Nor does [the Dialect Dictionary](http://www.thedialectdictionary.com/view/random/Southern+US/8000/), apparently.

Comment: @bart-leby: It looks like the daughter is asking her (wealthy?) father to bankroll her "too young" husband for another year's schooling before he settles down as the breadwinner for the next generation.

Comment: @bart-leby  - I don't hear the **be** in the youtube video I found of the song.  I hear the word "you" stretched to two syllables to make it fit the meter of the song.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Agreed on your bankrolling interpretation.

Comment: Compare Middle English **and** which can mean "if": *Wo hym that is allone! For and he falle, he hath non helpe to ryse*.(Chaucer, *Troilus and Criseyde*, l. 695).  "Woe to him who is alone. For if he fall, he has no help to stand up."  *if and* becomes **if'n**

Comment: **besee** can mean *deem*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I see nothing "Chaucerian" in a usage commented upon by [alphadictionary](https://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/southernese.html) pointing out *Southerners love their new suffix, **-n**, so much, they stick it everywhere. See **young'n** and **his'n.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I am not asserting that there's anything Chaucerian here (and said nothing of the sort). I'm pointing out that **and** means **if** in Middle English. The word continues to mean **if** and is in fact often joined with *if* redundantly in English dialects.  We find both "if an" and "an if". The former gets contracted to "ifn" and the latter to "nif".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: If there's no connection, why did you post the comment? And why are you inviting us to "compare" Chaucerian ***and = if*** with what I believe is a "folk etymology" (ascribing Texan hillbilly ***if'n*** to contraction/conflation of ***if + and***).

Comment: ...I'm not going looking for examples, but I'm pretty sure there will be *lots* of Shakespearean and later quotes using ***and*** where ***if*** is clearly the intended meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If I'm inviting you to do anything it is to withdraw the folk etymology that "Southerners love their new suffix -**n**".  This combination of "if" + "an" is well attested in the British English dialects from which Southern US English is derived.

Comment: How would "if'n" work grammatically if it means "if and"? Do you mean "and if"? If so, why would the words be reversed? To me, it just seems like "if'n" is a folksy way of saying "if."

Comment: _If'n => if + an_  makes more sense, but in that case it would be a contraction that is mostly used incorrectly. There is something sing-songy and folksy about ***if'n*** so it seems like an interesting possibility.

Comment: @Ringo: But **ifn** doesn't *mean* "if and" it is a contracted form of "if an" and it means **if**.  The 'n' is a shorted form of **an(d)** which also means "if".  Formulaic traditional folk ballads tend to preserve earlier linguistic forms. One can also emulate the language found in traditional folk ballads, to make a ballad seem "traditional".

Comment: Sounds reasonable enough to me!